# Export 3D object on Blender

Tags: augmented-reality, blender, unity3d-editor

I made a 3D object in blender and want to put it in unity. Already made into fbx, selected all the objects but when in unity there are many that don't have meshes. please help

I'm trying to create a 3D object in blender and export it to unity